# .gitignore for umbraco, including user-specific data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, umbraco, gitignore

Using visual studio and the [Umbraco NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UmbracoCms/), I'd like to setup a basic Umbraco installation containing:

- some umbraco packages, such as [Optimus](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/optimus/)
- some individual document types

This should be wrapped by a git repo.

Where possible, I'd like to **exclude generated/compiled files** by adding the affected paths/file extensions to the `.gitignore` file.

I started off using the official [umbraco .gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Umbraco.gitignore) which has the following entries:

```
# Note: VisualStudio gitignore rules may also be relevant

# Umbraco
# Ignore unimportant folders generated by Umbraco
**/App_Data/Logs/
**/App_Data/[Pp]review/
**/App_Data/TEMP/
**/App_Data/NuGetBackup/

# Ignore Umbraco content cache file
**/App_Data/umbraco.config

# Don't ignore Umbraco packages (VisualStudio.gitignore mistakes this for a NuGet packages folder)
# Make sure to include details from VisualStudio.gitignore BEFORE this
!**/App_Data/[Pp]ackages/
!**/[Uu]mbraco/[Dd]eveloper/[Pp]ackages

# ImageProcessor DiskCache 
**/App_Data/cache/
```

However, this would not include the database nor installed packages, so I also added the following entries*:

```
!**/Aa]pp_[Dd]ata/packages
!**/Aa]pp_[Dd]ata/Umbraco.sdf
!**/[Bb]in/*.pdb
!**/[Uu]mbraco/[Cc]onfig
```

- *see discussion [here](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/78957-what-should-i-commit-in-the-umbraco-folder)*

Using this configuration, ReSharper would list 3 errors which occur in the global web.config file:

```
my-umbraco-project\Web.config:87 Cannot resolve symbol 'Providers'
my-umbraco-project\Web.config:87 Cannot resolve symbol 'DefaultSessionStateProvider'
my-umbraco-project\Web.config:87 Invalid module qualification: Failed to resolve assembly System.Web.Providers
```

However, I can compile, log-in to my umbraco instance and even the pre-installed plugin would appear.

This basically leaves 2 questions:

- What do I additionally have to include in order to fix the 3 errors?
- Are there more compiled/generated files I could exclude?

Answer (score 3):

So here's the .gitignore we use without any issues:

```
[Oo]bj/
[Bb]in/
.nuget/
.vs/
_ReSharper.*
packages/
artifacts/
*.user
*.suo
*.userprefs
*.dbmdl
*DS_Store
*.sln.ide

# Umbraco
# Ignore unimportant folders generated by Umbraco
**/App_Data/Logs/
**/App_Data/[Pp]review/
**/App_Data/TEMP/
**/App_Data/NuGetBackup/

# Ignore Umbraco content cache file
**/App_Data/umbraco.config

# Don't ignore Umbraco packages (VisualStudio.gitignore mistakes this for a NuGet packages folder)
# Make sure to include details from VisualStudio.gitignore BEFORE this
!**/App_Data/[Pp]ackages/
!**/[Uu]mbraco/[Dd]eveloper/[Pp]ackages
!*UmbracoModelsBuilder.user

# ImageProcessor DiskCache
**/App_Data/cache/
```